# Methods in classes

Tags: ios, swift

These two snippets produced the same result.  What is numberOfTimes (method?)  How do you implement numberOfTimes?

```
class Counter
{
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int)
    {
        count += amount * times
    }

}
var counter = Counter()
counter.incrementBy(2, numberOfTimes: 7)


class Counter
{
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount: Int, times: Int)
    {
        count += amount * times
    }
}
var counter = Counter()
counter.incrementBy(2, times: 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

numberOfTimes is not a method, it is an external parameter name. Times is an internal parameter name. Check out [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_256) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but `numberOfTimes` is the external parameter name for the `times` argument.

The only difference is that in one case you have to call the method as

```
counter.incrementBy(2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

whereas if you leave it out, the local name is automatically used also as external

```
counter.incrementBy(2, times: 7)
```

More on the subject in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_255).

Answer (score 1):

That's an **external parameter name**, and it identifies the name you use when calling the function, whereas the local parameter name (`times` in your code) is how is the parameter is referenced from within the function.

Read more about [Function Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_255)